# What is the correct idiom for mapping a 0 value in a modulo n expression back to n?

Tags: syntax, coding-style, expression-construction, modular-arithmetic

What is the correct idiom for mapping the $0$ value in a modulo $n$ expression back to $n$.

For example if I want to be sure that any integer value maps back to the index for a character in the alphabet, I might use something like

```
letterIndex[l_]  = First@FirstPosition[ToUpperCase /@ Alphabet[], l];
letterIndex[l_, rot_] := Mod[letterIndex[l] + rot, 26] /. 0 -> 26;
```

But this look stupid to me and I feel like I'm missing something idiomatic to *Mathematica* (or to modular equivalences — which have always frustrated me — in general).

Comment: You mean `Mod[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 3, 1]`?

Comment: @Kuba: I don't get it?

Comment: I mean `Mod[x, 26]/.(0->26)` can be done with `Mod[x, 26, 1]`.

Comment: @Kuba: Duh! I should have looked a bit more closely at the doc!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what I've said in comments, you can write your function in shorter form:

```
letterIndex2[l_, rot_: 0] := Mod[First@ToCharacterCode[l] - 64 + rot, 26, 1]
```